# Sharepoint online rest api is returning xml instead of json

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have the following code

```
 this.context.spHttpClient.get(
    `${this.absoluteUrl}/?$select=Title&`,
    this.config, {
        headers:this.getHeaders,
    })
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      response.json().then((results) => { ...
```

Where I'm trying to find all list names of my Site, but I'm getting the following error

> sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_es-es_3ccc282fed5f46c40407a659977d1250.js:1078 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2

My header is the following

```
private getHeaders = { 
"Method": "GET",
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"odata-version": "",
};
```

and if I check network request header is sending the header.
I've also checked the result via web and it is returning everything on XML

I'm clueless any idea why is Sharepoint returning xml instead of json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
return this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists?$select=Title`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'odata-version': ''
        }
      });
  })
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {
    return response.json();
  });
```

Here are some reference codes on how to use spHttpClient with SharePoint: [GitHub reference](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud).

Comment: It works, thanks!, what is the difference between using headers like that, or how I did? the code seems almost the same but mine didn't work

Comment: I did both, but my upvotes doesn't count yet because I don't have that privilege, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using it wrong.

It needs to be as below:

1) Add the below import statement:

```
import { SPHttpClient, ISPHttpClientOptions , SPHttpClientResponse} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

2) After that you can use the `spHttpClient` as below:

```
var httpClientOptions : ISPHttpClientOptions = {};

httpClientOptions.headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'odata-version': ''
};

this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.absoluteUrl}?$select=Title`,
SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
httpClientOptions).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Tested this and it didn't work, I have the same poroblem because httpClientOptions.Headers are the same Headers I were trying to use and it still returns XML.